# How to Store Variable Data back from file in Java

Tags: java

Problem Defined: I store bookname and bookauthor variable data in file using tostring to buffer writer, When i run program next time program read the file but not to store data back to the variable
Please write read code and and variable data storing from file in JAVA

...........................................................................................................................................................
Three Classes One is Main Class,Second is filewriting class and One Class having book add function.Source Code is given here

```
   import java.util.Scanner; 
   import java.io.*;
   public class AddBook extends Filewriting{
   public int add;
   public AddBook(int add){this.add=add;}
   public String bookname[] = new String[15];
   public String bookauthor[] = new String[15];
   public int price[] = new int[15];
   public void addbook(){

  for(int i=0;i<add;i++){   
  System.out.println("Enter the Book Title:");
  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
  bookname[i]=input.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Enter the Book Author:");
  Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
  bookauthor[i]=input.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Enter the Book Price:");
  Scanner input1=new Scanner(System.in);
  price[i]=input1.nextInt();
 }
 }
public String toString(int j)
 {                      
  return  String.format("BookName:%s%nBookAuthor:%s%nBookPrice:%d%n%n................................................................................................................................%n",bookname[j],bookauthor[j],price[j]);
}   
}

 import java.util.*;

 import java.io.*;

 public class Filewriting  {
 public int add;
    public void filewriting(){

     System.out.println("How many Books you want to added:");
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
      add=in.nextInt();

        try{
      File file = new File("Hello1.txt");
      // creates New file
      file.createNewFile(); 
       Writer writer = new FileWriter("Hello1.txt",true);
      BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);

      AddBook obj=new AddBook(add);
      obj.addbook();

       for ( int i = 0; i < add; i++){
     // bufferWriter.write(obj.bookname[i] + obj.bookauthor[i] +obj.price[i]);
       bufferWriter.write(obj.toString(i));
       }
      bufferWriter.close();



        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
```

}

```
/*  // Creates a FileReader Object
  FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); 
  char [] a = new char[50];
  fr.read(a);   // reads the content to the array

  for(char c : a)
     System.out.print(c);   // prints the characters one by one
  fr.close(); */
  }
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.io.*;
  public class Test{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to Add Books:");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 to Check Store Books again in Variable:");
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=input.nextInt();
    if(i==1){
        System.out.println("You Press B");
        Filewriting fw=new Filewriting();
        fw.filewriting();
    }
    if(i==2)
    {
         Filewriting fw=new Filewriting();
         AddBook obj=new AddBook(fw.add);
         for ( int j = 0; j < 2; j++) // for storing 2 variables data
      {
      System.out.println(obj.bookname[j]); // just check bookname,shows null
       }
     }
// Please write code that we read the file as well as data is stored again in Variables     

    }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you did not describe a specific programming problem.

Answer (score -1):

I see You can write Data in File as not well.From your Code it is impossible to Store data in your variables.You must set and get Methods in your program in order to store variables.Following Program Code is help you to storing file data to variable perfectly.
................................................................................

```
public class Book {
public String name;
public String author;
public int price;

    public Book(){
        this("","",0);
    }
    public Book(String name,String author,int price){
        setName(name);
        setAuthor(author);
        setPrice(price);
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=  name ;

    }
    public void setAuthor(String author){
        this.author = author ;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price){
        this.price = price ;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }
    public int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
  }
    import java.io.*;

    import java.util.*;
   public class ReadText {
   Scanner input,a;
   public void OpenBook(){
    File f = new File("Hello1.txt");
    if ( f.exists()){
        System.out.println("Welcome Ur File IS Open....."+f);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error... File DOes not exits");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        input = new Scanner(new File("Hello1.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void ReadBook(){
    Book b = new Book();
    while((input.hasNext())){
        b.setName(input.nextLine());
        b.setAuthor(input.nextLine());
        b.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()));
    System.out.printf("Book Name:%s\nBook Author:%s\nBook Price:%d\n",b.getName(),b.getAuthor(),b.getPrice());
    }
}
```

}